# wxwidget - issue of wxEVT_LEAVE_WINDOW event

Tags: wxwidgets

I'd like to implement a card style UI(as the screen shot), card is using a wxPanel as a container, a static text and a static bmp in the panel. the card will zoom in and color changed when mouse on it, when the mouse leave the card, size and color will recover as normal state. I add some logic in onEnter and onLeave of wxPanel to handle zoom and color change. the card works fine in most of cases, but if mouse move quickly, multiple cards will be selected. From output log, it seems the issue happens in OnLeave, !GetClientRect().Contains(event.GetPosition()) = false, even the mouse actually has been out of the rect of the card. how can the card work as expected even mouse move quickly?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBOfy.png)

```
void TypeCard::OnEnter(wxMouseEvent& event) {
  wxRect rect = GetClientRect();
  wxPoint pnt = event.GetPosition();
  TRACELOG_WARNING("@@@@@@ On Enter left=%d top=%d width=%d height=%d", rect.GetLeft(), rect.GetTop(), rect.GetWidth(), rect.GetHeight());
  TRACELOG_WARNING("&&&&&& On Enter x=%d y=%d", pnt.x, pnt.y);
  if (GetClientRect().Contains(event.GetPosition()) && !selected_ ) {
    TRACELOG_WARNING("&&&&&&On Enter = true");
    if (m_bZoomEnabled) {
      ZoomCard(zoom_in, 5, 5);
    }
    selected_ = true;
  } else {
    TRACELOG_WARNING("*****************************************************On Enter = false selected_ = %d", (int)selected_ );
  }

  //  have_focus_ = true;
  Refresh(false);
  Update();
  event.Skip();
}

void TypeCard::OnLeave(wxMouseEvent& event) {
  wxRect rect = GetClientRect();
  wxPoint pnt = event.GetPosition();
  TRACELOG_WARNING("@@@@@@ On OnLeave left=%d top=%d width=%d height=%d", rect.GetLeft(), rect.GetTop(), rect.GetWidth(), rect.GetHeight());
  TRACELOG_WARNING("&&&&&& On OnLeave x=%d y=%d", pnt.x, pnt.y);
  //  if (!GetClientRect().Contains(event.GetPosition())) {
  if (!rect.Contains(pnt)) {
    if (m_bZoomEnabled) {
      ZoomCard(zoom_out, 5, 5);
    }
    selected_ = false;
  } else {
    TRACELOG_WARNING("*****************************************************On OnLeave = false");
  }
  if (!selected_) {
    //      have_focus_ = false;
    Refresh(false);
    Update();
  }

  event.Skip();
}  
void TypeCard::OnPaint(wxPaintEvent& event) {
  wxPaintDC dc(this);
  wxColour colour = selected_ ? CARD_SELECT_BACKGROUND_COLOUR : COMPONENT_UNSELECT_BACKGROUND_COLOUR;
  wxCursor cur = selected_ ? wxCURSOR_HAND : wxCURSOR_ARROW;
  dc.SetPen(wxPen(colour));
  dc.SetBrush(wxBrush(colour));
  this->SetCursor(cur);

  const wxWindowList& list = this->GetChildren();
  for (wxWindowList::compatibility_iterator node = list.GetFirst(); node; node = node->GetNext()) {
    wxWindow* current = node->GetData();
    if (current) {
      current->SetBackgroundColour(colour);
      current->SetCursor(cur);
    }
  }
  dc.DrawRectangle(0, 0, this->GetSize().GetWidth(), GetSize().GetHeight());
}
```

Comment: which OS? which wx version/toolkit? can you reproduce it in a sample?

Comment: the demo worked on Win7 with wx3.03. I tried implement the same logic on a panel without text and bmp in it, the behavior is as expected.

Comment: It might be easier if you draw the image/images and calculate the bounding rectangle (wxRect) and then check whether the mouse is in that rectangle to take any action.